# Why monitoring CPU and Sample are not available on visualVM

Tags: visualvm

Since a few days VisualVM doesn't work very well.
I don't know why monitoring CPU and Sample are not avalables.

Thank you.
Jérôme

```
Version: 1.8.0_45 (Build 1380-140910); platform 20140910-unknown-revn
System: Windows 7 (6.1) Service Pack 1, amd64 64bit
Java: 1.8.0_45; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02, mixed mode)
Vendor: Oracle Corporation, http://java.oracle.com/
Environment: Cp1252; fr_FR (visualvm)

User directory: C:\Users\Jerome\AppData\Roaming\VisualVM\8u40
Cache directory: C:\Users\Jerome\AppData\Local\VisualVM\Cache\8u40
Clusters: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib\visualvm\platform
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib\visualvm\visualvm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib\visualvm\profiler
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this "not issue" ;)
It doesn't work because java app was running from eclipse and i didn't use jre (in eclipse) from jdk.

I modyfied this and it works.